# difference between history plugin and state history plugin

Tags: plugin, history

What I know is,

- **history_plugin** : plugins that enable store sort of historical data like action traces, transaction traces.
- **history_api_plugin** : plugins that enable to use /history/* APIs.

So, state_history_plugin was introduced at v1.5.0, and this can be configured at config.ini like

- plugin = eosio::state_history_plugin
- trace-history = false
- ... ETC ...

Also, I found this (https://github.com/acoutts/EOS-state-history-API) while reading this post (https://medium.com/@eos42/scalable-full-history-nodes-b4eccf113d57). But I think this repo is just for mongo db plugin.

So, my question is...

1. What is **difference between history and state history?** and how can query state_history_plugin data?
2. Is there any **state_history_api_plugin** for RPC? (like /v1/state_history/get_actions)

Answer (score 4):

I asked my friend Andrew Coutts this question on your behalf, and he said:

> So the state history plugin is just a piece of the equation.
>
> - The history plugin exposes the RPC API that we're all familiar with.
> - The state history plugin saves state data to a new flat file format that’s designed to be read from external components and is faster to
>     rebuild than replaying the chain with the history plugin.
> - State history plugin exposes a websocket interface for something to connect to and read the block / state data from the additional new
>     state history files stored in the data directory.
> - There are 2 examples of state history websocket clients on the eosio GitHub:
>
>   - C++: https://github.com/EOSIO/fill-postgresql
>   - JavaScript: https://github.com/EOSIO/test-state-history
>
> More advantages to the new flat file and websocket approach:
>
> - Multiple fillers can connect to nodeos and read simultaneously from different locations in the flat file.
> - When you need to rebuild your application state nodeos doesn’t need to be replayed as you’re reading from external files now.